# Minecraft plugin read JSON data

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I would like to create my own Minecraft plugin.

**Problem:** Moderators must type in this command:

```
/mod login {KEY-FROM-JSONFILE}
```

And if the *playername* and the *key* that they gave are correct, the Console must execute the following command:

```
/manuadd {playername} Mod
```

The *key* and the *playername* are generated on the website stored in the JSON file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is your attempt at solving this issue? What library are you using?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this. I would like to get information on how to do this.
I am using the spigot jar file

Comment: Couldn't some random person just type in-game /manuadd MySelf Mod?

Answer (score 0):

To read the JSON data I suggest using a library like google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [SimplixStorage](https://github.com/Simplix-Softworks/SimplixStorage) and if you use simplix you can do something like this

```
public Json getJsonFromURL(URL url, String name, String path){
        Json json;
        try (InputStream input = url.openStream()) {
            json = new Json(name, path, input);
            return json;
        } catch (Exception e){
            //Exceprion handling
        }
        return null;
    }
```